# How to set the item text color to white of Spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am working on demo application in which I am using `Spinner` and have a black like background color so Spinner selected item color is also by default black so it's in not visible.

I want through xml or update style to change this color to white so that it will be visible over black.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/country" />
```

[image]

Any way to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: set style with parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Dark.ProgressBar"

Comment: Are you trying to make the text white only on a selected item?

Comment: @CSmith How can you please explain ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try handling this in your OnItemSelectedListener. I think the following should work. It takes the view of the selected item, finds the TextView within it (Spinner views have a TextView child with an id of text1), and sets its color.

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            TextView tmpView = (TextView) mySpinner.getSelectedView().findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tmpView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // do stuff

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a style in your res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="mySpinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Dark.ProgressBar" />
```

and reference this style on your Spinner:

```
<Spinner style="@style/mySpinner" ... />
```

The parent style, Widget.Holo.Dark.ProgressBar should get you a spinner appropriately styled for a dark background.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html for info on Styles.  You can sniff around the SDK res/ folders to learn about built-in styles.

Comment: I am using support library appcompat. Now I am getting cannot resolve @android:style/Widget.Holo.Dark.ProgressBar

Comment: Please note that I don't want like same I added in the question. I simply want selected text color to white.